# Source not found error on button click to change activity

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent

I'm simply trying to trigger a new activity from a button click but every time I click said button I get an error saying "source not found" with "edit source lookup path" underneath. This seems to be a pretty common problem and usually seems to be associated with either the OnClickListener method or the source path not pointing at the right files.

Here's the file for the original activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homebutton2);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DisplayExplanation.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);   
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

I'm sure that there isn't a problem with the OnClickListener because if I replace the intent with a toast, the toast appears just fine.

I've also restarted the project to make absolutely sure that the source path is right; it's pointing at the right .jar files and my project folder. The API matches that in the manifest too.

For completeness, here is the activity that I'm trying to open:

```
public class DisplayExplanation extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_explanation);
    }

}
```

I'd really appreciate any help you can give me on this - seems like I've been banging my head against a wall for hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Current_Activity.this, DisplayExplanation.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DisplayExplanation.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

to start New Activity on Button Click always pass Current Activity Context instead of Current View context like you are passing context for starting Activity

Comment: check if the DisplayExplanation class is declared in manifest

Comment: Tremendously useful thanks so much! As suspected, I was missing something simple.

Comment: Also, I should probably mention for anyone suffering from this problem in the future that the xml file I was calling in the new activity wasn't written properly. I had Textview rather than TextView. Amazing how much difference a missed capital can make!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayExplanation.class);

    startActivity(intent);
```

instead of...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DisplayExplanation.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DisplayExplanation.class);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayExplanation.class);
```

Comment: why? please add descriptive answer

Comment: @hotveryspicy I think it is self explanatory.since he is passing wrong context.